# error when running: can not format given object as a number

Tags: javascript, java, formatting

So I have to make a code that will come up with the factorial of numbers 1 through 9 when you enter them.  So I has to ask for you to enter a number 1 through 9 and then it will give you the factoral of  the number.  I am working in text pad and it compiles with out errors but when I run it after I enter the number it says.  Num has to be int and factorial has to be long.

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Number
at java.text.DecimalFormat.format(Unknown Source)
at java.text.Format.format(Unknown Source)
at FactorialApp.main(FactorialApp.java:43)
```

Here is my code.  I'm not sure what part is causing it.  Does it have to do with formatting the message?

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class FactorialApp
{
public static void main(String[] arge)
{



    long factioral=1;


    int num;



    System.out.print("Welcome to the Factoral Calculator" + "\n" + "\n" + "Enter an integer between 1 and 9: "); //Welcome users the the application

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    num = sc.nextInt();
    for (int i=2;i<=num; i++){
    factorial=factorial*i;}

    String choice = "y";
    while (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {


    // Format and display the results

                NumberFormat number = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();

                String message =
                ("\n" + "Loan amount:           " + number.format("factorial") + "\n");

    System.out.println(message);  // Output the formated message

    } // End While



} // End main ()

} // End Class
```

Comment: Where's the javascript part?

Comment: You've tried to format the string `"factorial"` as a number. I think you just meant to pass `factorial` (the variable).

Comment: Thank you for answering. What do you mean by pass factorial? That probably is what I meant to do I'm just not sure how.

Comment: Just remove the quotes.